# Proving the set of the $n$-th roots of unity form a cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

[image]

All I recall about $\pi$, is that it is the torus and that it is a subgroup of $\mathbb C^\times$.

I read about the proof that forms a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb C^\times$, but not sure about this one.

Answer (score 1):

The complex numbers less $0$ are a group under multiplication.  The roots inherit associativity, which is usually the hard one. You need to show closure and inverses.

Comment: Would this be correct:

Comment: (u^k) = (e^[(2πk)/n]) and <u> = {u,...,u^k,...u^n = 1}.  Then (u^k)^n = (u^n)^k = 1^k = 1*1...*1 = 1

Comment: You remark that the inverse of $\exp(2ik\pi/n)$ is $\exp(2i(n-k)\pi/n)$ to show inverses.  To show closure, $\exp(2ik\pi/n)\exp(2im\pi/n)=\exp(2i(k+m)\pi/n)$ and that is still an $n$th root